# Can't adjust labels correctly in barplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to plot the frequency of used Emoji in a text with the Emoji as labels in a side-by-side bargraph. This is the **artificial** test data:

```
test <- structure(list(Sender = c("al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", 
"al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", 
"al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", 
"al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", 
"al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", 
"al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", 
"al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Jabara, Abdul Khaliq", "al-Ullah, Shahla", 
"al-Ullah, Shahla", "al-Ullah, Shahla", "al-Ullah, Shahla", "al-Ullah, Shahla", 
"al-Ullah, Shahla", "al-Ullah, Shahla", "al-Ullah, Shahla", "al-Ullah, Shahla", 
"al-Ullah, Shahla", "al-Ullah, Shahla", "al-Ullah, Shahla", "al-Ullah, Shahla", 
"al-Ullah, Shahla", "al-Ullah, Shahla", "al-Ullah, Shahla", "al-Ullah, Shahla", 
"al-Ullah, Shahla"), Emoji = c("Backhand_Index_Pointing_Left:_Medium-Light_Skin_Tone", 
"Children_Crossing", "Cinema", "Family:_Woman,_Boy", "Flag:_Antigua_&_Barbuda", 
"Flag:_Bahrain", "Man_Bouncing_Ball:_Medium_Skin_Tone", "Man_Gesturing_OK:_Dark_Skin_Tone", 
"Man_Gesturing_OK:_Light_Skin_Tone", "Melon", "Middle_Finger:_Medium-Dark_Skin_Tone", 
"Moon_Viewing_Ceremony", "Person_Bouncing_Ball:_Dark_Skin_Tone", 
"Person_Tipping_Hand:_Dark_Skin_Tone", "Police_Officer:_Medium_Skin_Tone", 
"Spouting_Whale", "Wheelchair_Symbol", "Woman_Farmer:_Medium-Light_Skin_Tone", 
"Woman:_Medium-Light_Skin_Tone,_Blond_Hair", "Backhand_Index_Pointing_Left:_Medium-Light_Skin_Tone", 
"Children_Crossing", "Cinema", "Family:_Woman,_Boy", "Flag:_Antigua_&_Barbuda", 
"Flag:_Bahrain", "Man_Gesturing_OK:_Dark_Skin_Tone", "Man_Gesturing_OK:_Light_Skin_Tone", 
"Melon", "Middle_Finger:_Medium-Dark_Skin_Tone", "Moon_Viewing_Ceremony", 
"Person_Bouncing_Ball:_Dark_Skin_Tone", "Person_Tipping_Hand:_Dark_Skin_Tone", 
"Police_Officer:_Medium_Skin_Tone", "Spouting_Whale", "Wheelchair_Symbol", 
"Woman_Farmer:_Medium-Light_Skin_Tone", "Woman:_Medium-Light_Skin_Tone,_Blond_Hair"
), n = c(5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L), Glyph = c(`Backhand_Index_Pointing_Left:_Medium-Light_Skin_Tone` = "", 
Children_Crossing = "", Cinema = "", `Family:_Woman,_Boy` = "‍", 
`Flag:_Antigua_&_Barbuda` = "", `Flag:_Bahrain` = "", 
`Man_Bouncing_Ball:_Medium_Skin_Tone` = "⛹‍♂️", `Man_Gesturing_OK:_Dark_Skin_Tone` = "‍♂️", 
`Man_Gesturing_OK:_Light_Skin_Tone` = "‍♂️", Melon = "", 
`Middle_Finger:_Medium-Dark_Skin_Tone` = "", Moon_Viewing_Ceremony = "", 
`Person_Bouncing_Ball:_Dark_Skin_Tone` = "⛹", `Person_Tipping_Hand:_Dark_Skin_Tone` = "", 
`Police_Officer:_Medium_Skin_Tone` = "", Spouting_Whale = "", 
Wheelchair_Symbol = "♿", `Woman_Farmer:_Medium-Light_Skin_Tone` = "‍", 
`Woman:_Medium-Light_Skin_Tone,_Blond_Hair` = "‍♀️", 
`Backhand_Index_Pointing_Left:_Medium-Light_Skin_Tone` = "", 
Children_Crossing = "", Cinema = "", `Family:_Woman,_Boy` = "‍", 
`Flag:_Antigua_&_Barbuda` = "", `Flag:_Bahrain` = "", 
`Man_Gesturing_OK:_Dark_Skin_Tone` = "‍♂️", `Man_Gesturing_OK:_Light_Skin_Tone` = "‍♂️", 
Melon = "", `Middle_Finger:_Medium-Dark_Skin_Tone` = "", 
Moon_Viewing_Ceremony = "", `Person_Bouncing_Ball:_Dark_Skin_Tone` = "⛹", 
`Person_Tipping_Hand:_Dark_Skin_Tone` = "", `Police_Officer:_Medium_Skin_Tone` = "", 
Spouting_Whale = "", Wheelchair_Symbol = "♿", `Woman_Farmer:_Medium-Light_Skin_Tone` = "‍", 
`Woman:_Medium-Light_Skin_Tone,_Blond_Hair` = "‍♀️"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -37L))
```

I want to visualize it like this:

```
 ggplot(test, aes(x = Sender, y = n,fill = Emoji, label = Glyph)) +
     theme_minimal() +
     geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
     theme(legend.title = element_text("Emoji")) +
     geom_label(aes(label = Glyph, fill = Emoji),
                family="Noto Color Emoji",
                label.size = NA,
                fill = alpha(c("white"),0),
                size = 10,+                
     position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single"))
```

But some of the labels are not in the center of their corresponding bars but shiftes side to side:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When positioning labels make sure that you use the same position for both the bars and the labels, i.e. do `geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single"))`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(test, aes(x = Sender, y = n, fill = Emoji, label = Glyph)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single")) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text("Emoji")) +
  geom_label(aes(label = Glyph, fill = Emoji),
    family = "Noto Color Emoji",
    label.size = NA,
    fill = alpha(c("white"), 0),
    size = 10,
    position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single")
  )
```

[image]